# How do I open a new window and show an alert in it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two html files (missions.html and missionInfo.html). In missions.html , I have called a function "open" which is defined in a java script file and is as follows:

```
function open()   
{   
    alert("Hello");   
    window.open("missionInfo.html" , "_self");   
    alert("Hello Again");   
}
```

I want to show an alert box saying "Hello" in missions.html then open missionInfo.html and in this newly opened file I want to show an alert box saying "Hello Again" . But when I'm calling this function in mission.html it isn't executing completely . It shows first alert box then opens the missionInfo.html file and then stops executing . It is not showing the second alert box which was supposed to be shown in missionInfo.html

Comment: Can't reproduce. I see "Hello", then "Hello Again" and after a second the the second alert automatically disappears and the page is replaced with the new one.

Comment: Or if you defined the `open` function in global scope and rewrote `window.open` , then I see "Hello" indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

this is a fairly simple task anyway.

At first, you have one page say, index.html in which when you defined `open` function in it to open a new document `missionInfo.html`.

All you have to do is just add code to show an alert on the `missionInfo.html` page.

So now your `missionInfo.html` should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    ... 
    <script>
        alert('Hello from Mission Info')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's it!